# Change formula based on value of cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm calculating the a Loan payment with PMT function and was wondering how I can change the percentage based on the outstanding loan.

Say if the outstanding loan drops below 80% of the total loan value I want to change the percentage used to calculate the payment.

I tried with the IF function but that doesn't seem to work

```
K1=0,22
L1=0,21
K2=Total loan value
G2=loan value after periodic payment.

IF(G2>K$2*0,8; PMT(K$1; 360; K$2; 0;0); PMT(L$1; 360; K$2; 0;0))
```

actual sheet: [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Pau15CZbta-Yh-BgJOkOuVFSxRxkj-hTWJYO-CWFT4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you mean exactly, "it doesn't seem to work"? I replicated your cells and formula and it's working, reacting to changes in G2 etc. Perhaps you can post a link to a copy of your spreadsheet indicating what do you expect to happen.

Comment: @ttarchala I added a link to the sheet I want to have the mortgage amount `E column` reflect the amount that has been redeem every month

The `if function` works now If I dont fill in anything But depending on how much is already been paid in the mortgage the PMT needs to change the interest rate